# Importing lodash into angular2 + typescript application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash, es6-module-loader

I am having a hard time trying to get the lodash modules imported. I've setup my project using npm+gulp, and keep hitting the same wall. I've tried the regular lodash, but also lodash-es.

The lodash npm package: (has an index.js file in the package root folder)

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

Results in:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lodash'.
```

The lodash-es npm package: (has a default export in lodash.js i the package root folder)

```
import * as _ from 'lodash-es/lodash';
```

Results in:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lodash-es'.
```

Both the gulp task and webstorm report the same issue.

Funny fact, this returns no error:

```
import 'lodash-es/lodash';
```

... but of course there is no "_" ...

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    tsPath = 'app/**/*.ts';

gulp.task('ts', function () {
    var tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
    
    gulp.src([tsPath])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./../js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch([tsPath], ['ts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['ts', 'watch']);
```

If I understood correctly, moduleResolution:'node' in my tsconfig should point the import statements to the node_modules folder, where lodash and lodash-es are installed. I've also tried lots of different ways to import: absolute paths, relative paths, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

If necessary I can provide a small zip file to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I ran into this problem too.  The lodash library does not have typecript definitions included in modular format so the import statements do not work. The only work around now it seems is make a script reference to lodash in your index.html file then reference the lodash.d.ts in your typescript files.  hopefully this will be fixed soon.  if there is another work around for this i would like to hear it.

Comment: the zip file would be great. But it looks like you are not using any module loader (like jspm or webpack) ? How are you loading Angular, via script tags? better post the html as well. I recommend you use webpack as module loader, see here an example -> https://github.com/jhades/angular2-library-example/tree/master/examples/webpack and this is a minimal starter -> https://github.com/jhades/ng2-webpack-minimal

Comment: See this link: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4889

Comment: I ended up just adding this to my mail ts file:  

/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

Comment: As of today none of the above works.  I am using the angular.2.4.4 stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way of importing and using lodash in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991178/correct-way-of-importing-and-using-lodash-in-angular)

Answer (score 505, accepted):

Here is how to do this as of Typescript 2.0:
(tsd and typings are being deprecated in favor of the following):

```
$ npm install --save lodash

# This is the new bit here: 
$ npm install --save-dev @types/lodash
```

Then, in your .ts file:

Either:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

Or (as suggested by @Naitik):

```
import _ from "lodash";
```

I'm not positive what the difference is. We use and prefer the first syntax. However, some report that the first syntax doesn't work for them, and someone else has commented that the latter syntax is incompatible with lazy loaded webpack modules. YMMV.

Edit on Feb 27th, 2017:

According to @Koert below, `import * as _ from "lodash";` is the only working syntax as of Typescript 2.2.1, lodash 4.17.4, and @types/lodash 4.14.53. He says that the other suggested import syntax gives the error "has no default export".

Comment: I can confirm that this works when using `typescript 2.0.3`. Indeed removing `typings` in favor of `@types` npm package is much cleaner.

Comment: `import * as _ from "lodash";` wasn't working for me but `import _ from "lodash";` does.

Comment: A word of warning, I've found the `import _ from "lodash"` syntax to be incompatible with lazy loaded webpack modules. Not sure why, I haven't investigated in detail.

Comment: Thanks @TomMakin for the word of warning, and thanks Naitik for pointing out the alternative syntax.

Comment: @Taytay How do I set `_` as a global constant so that I only `import` once e.g. in the root? I would rather not have to write `import * as _ from "lodash";` at the top of every `.ts` file, I'd just like `_` to be there.

Comment: @GFoley83: Someone asked something similar about React: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3180  Based on that issue, this is considered somewhat of an anti-pattern once you are using typical modules. However, I believe you could do it by having the lodash script loaded separately as part of your page load, putting it in the global scope. Then, you should be able to do this in a file that is included by all your files.
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/index.d.ts"/>
That declares `_` as part of the global scope.

Comment: @Damiani I disagree, I think importing _ and referencing functions off that is a lot cleaner than having function references - as you can see that the function came from lodash. If you're using tree shaking it shouldn't bear a difference on the production builds.

Comment: Can you be more specific @Toolkit?

Comment: Can you be more specific @030?

Comment: Typings is being deprecated too? Man, I just switched to that from TSD.

Comment: @Taytay `import * as _ from "lodash";` works for me. I'm using lodash 4.17.4 and @types/lodash 4.14.53. With Typescript 2.2.1. Importing without "as" results in "has no default export".

Comment: import _ from "lodash"; doesn't work anymore in 2.0. You have to use import * as _ from "lodash";

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Comment: This should be used only in development, not production, so use save-dev:

`npm install --save-dev @types/lodash`

If you're seeing weird issues and bugs, try this:

`npm install --save-dev @types/lodash@4.14.50`

Comment: Adding confirmation that I could only get this by using the former syntax `import * as _ from "lodash"` -- i am using tsc ^2.2.2 and webpack ^2.4.1 with ts-loader ^2.0.3 -- i am betting something changes in one dependency along the way

Comment: `npm install --save-dev @types/lodash` will be the wise choice

Comment: As of Angular 6.1.2 this works fine: import * as _ from 'lodash'; using typescript 2.7.2 and lodash 4.17.10 with @types/lodash 4.14.116

Comment: To decrease `lodash` bundle size .. I found this [article](https://dev.to/johnphamous/how-to-make-your-bundle-size-smaller-if-you-re-using-lodash-with-angular-55lh) very helpful

Comment: `import * as _ from "lodash"` imports all non-default exports from lodash and puts them in an object named `_`. That means this will still work even if lodash doesn't have a default export.

Answer (score 70):

**Update September 26, 2016:**

As @Taytay's answer says, instead of the 'typings' installations that we used a few months ago, we can now use:

```
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

Here are some additional references supporting that answer:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash
- [TypeScript typings in NPM @types org packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548066/typescript-typings-in-npm-types-org-packages)

If still using the typings installation, see the comments below (by others) regarding '''--ambient''' and '''--global'''.

Also, in the new Quick Start, config is no longer in index.html; it's now in systemjs.config.ts (if using SystemJS).

**Original Answer:**

This worked on my mac (after installing Angular 2 as per [Quick Start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)):

```
sudo npm install typings --global
npm install lodash --save 
typings install lodash --ambient --save
```

You will find various files affected, e.g.

- /typings/main.d.ts
- /typings.json
- /package.json

Angular 2 Quickstart uses System.js, so I added 'map' to the config in index.html as follows:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      lodash: 'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
    }
  });
```

Then in my .ts code I was able to do:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

console.log('lodash version:', _.VERSION);
```

Edits from mid-2016:

As @tibbus mentions, in some contexts, you need:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

If starting from [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed), and if you don't want to import every time, you can skip the map and import steps and just uncomment the lodash line in tools/config/project.config.ts.

To get my tests working with lodash, I also had to add a line to the files array in karma.conf.js:

```
'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js',
```

Comment: I see that this resolves my TypeScript issues, but loading the page in a browser I still see the error that it can't find module lodash. It looks like it's making a failed xhr request to '/lodash' instead of node_modules.

Comment: @zack did you miss  `map: {
      lodash: 'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
    }`  in the `System.config` ?

Comment: For me it works only with **import * as _ from 'lodash';**

Comment: What does the `--ambient` parameter do?

Comment: ...and why do we need to write `import * as _ from 'lodash'` instead of `import _ from 'lodash'` ?

Comment: @smartmouse `--ambient` is a former for `--global`. The latter is used in 1.x and moving forward.  Though, I don't think the latest lodash 4.x will compile as global module like that.

Comment: Yes, lodash typings won't save with --global flag because it's an external module.

Comment: @Toolkit I see you removed a similar comment from a similar answer. Is it still true here?

Comment: eventually this works for me,thanks. I think the most important step is `map: { lodash: 'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js' }`

Comment: use this way, I cannot load nth, anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 27):

### First things first

`npm install --save lodash`

`npm install -D @types/lodash`

### Load the full lodash library

```
//some_module_file.ts
// Load the full library...
import * as _ from 'lodash' 
// work with whatever lodash functions we want
_.debounce(...) // this is typesafe (as expected)
```

### **OR** load only functions we are going to work with

```
import * as debounce from 'lodash/debounce'
//work with the debounce function directly
debounce(...)   // this too is typesafe (as expected)
```

---

### `UPDATE - March 2017`

I'm currently working with `ES6 modules`, and recently i was able to work with `lodash` like so:

```
// the-module.js (IT SHOULD WORK WITH TYPESCRIPT - .ts AS WELL) 
// Load the full library...
import _ from 'lodash' 
// work with whatever lodash functions we want
_.debounce(...) // this is typesafe (as expected)
...
```

#### OR `import` specific `lodash functionality`:

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'
//work with the debounce function directly
debounce(...)   // this too is typesafe (as expected)
...
```

**NOTE** - the difference being `* as` is not required in the `syntax`

---

#### References:

[image]

Good Luck.

Comment: "Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules"

Comment: @Toolkit.  Thank you for pointing it out.  I have updated the answer.  Please check if this solutions works and mark appropriately.

Comment: `import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'` yields `TS1192: Module node_modules/@types/lodash/debounce has no default export` when `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false`

Comment: @kross i just did `npm i --save @types/lodash` and peeked into the `@types/lodash` folder and found the file `debounce.d.ts` to be there and thus it should work.  You can checkout more info on `tsconfig.json` here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html.  I've also included a snapshot from there in the answer.  Good Luck...

Comment: I stand by my previous comment. There is not currently a default export in the types file, so this does not work with allowSyntheticDefaultImports false.

Comment: @kross  Also note that adding the `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` compiler option in your tsconfig.json file might be needed to avoid any error.

Answer (score 23):

Step 1: Modify package.json file to include lodash in the dependencies.

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12",
"lodash":"^4.12.0",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6"  }
```

Step 2:I am using SystemJs module loader in my angular2 application. So I would be modifying the systemjs.config.js file to map lodash.

```
(function(global) {

// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'lodash':                    'node_modules/lodash'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'lodash':                    {main:'index.js', defaultExtension:'js'}
};

var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
];

// add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
}

// filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

System.config(config);})(this);
```

Step 3: Now  do npm install

Step 4: To use lodash in your file.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
let firstIndexOfElement=_.findIndex(array,criteria);
```

Comment: How does your solution take care of the TypeScript typings?
The npm lodash package does not seem to include the .d.ts files.

Answer (score 14):

Since Typescript 2.0, @types npm modules are used to import typings.

```
# Implementation package (required to run)
$ npm install --save lodash

# Typescript Description
$ npm install --save @types/lodash
```

Now since this question has been answered I'll go into how to efficiently import lodash

The failsafe way to import the entire library (in main.ts)

```
import 'lodash';
```

## This is the new bit here:

Implementing a lighter lodash with the functions you require

```
import chain from "lodash/chain";
import value from "lodash/value";
import map from "lodash/map";
import mixin from "lodash/mixin";
import _ from "lodash/wrapperLodash";
```

source: https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba#.kg6azugbd

PS: The above article is an interesting read on improving build time and reducing app size

Comment: For TSC this is great, however it gives other issues with bundlers. any chance you managed to get this working through rollup? aurelia-cli also gives issues with it :(.

**Rollup error**: 'default' is not exported by node_modules\lodash\kebabCase.js

**Aurelia cli error**:  no such file or directory, open '/experimental\au-proj\node_modules\lodash\lodash\kebabCase.js'

Comment: Seems the @types/lodash doesn't support the lighter syntax yet. 

`error TS1192: Module '"node_modules/@types/lodash/chain/index"' has no default export.`

And so forth for other modules attempting the shorter `import chain from "lodash/chain"` imports

Answer (score 10):

I successfully imported lodash in my project with the following commands:

```
npm install lodash --save
typings install lodash --save
```

Then i imported it in the following way:

`import * as _ from 'lodash';`

and in systemjs.config.js i defined this:

`map: { 'lodash' : 'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js' }`

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem, but in an Angular2 app, and this article just solve it: https://medium.com/@s_eschweiler/using-external-libraries-with-angular-2-87e06db8e5d1#.p6gra5eli

Summary of the article:

1. Installing the Library `npm install lodash --save`
2. Add TypeScript Definitions for Lodash `tsd install underscore`
3. Including Script `<script src="node_modules/lodash/index.js"></script>`
4. Configuring SystemJS `System.config({
             paths: {
                 lodash: './node_modules/lodash/index.js'`
5. Importing Module `import * as _ from ‘lodash’;`

I hope it can be useful for your case too

Comment: tsd is deprecated now. You should use typings

Answer (score 7):

Another elegant solution is to get only what you need, not import all the lodash

```
import {forEach,merge} from "lodash";
```

and then use it in your code

```
forEach({'a':2,'b':3}, (v,k) => {
   console.log(k);
})
```

Comment: Does this actually work? I've tried this and it doesn't seem to change the size of the bundle.

Comment: Maybe not back then, but now yes. It's tree shaking at it's best

Comment: @Pian0_M4n maybe i'm doing it wrong but tried with angular cli 1.4.4 tree shaking didn't work

Comment: @alexKhymenko can you post the error? Is it connected to lodash?

Comment: @Pian0_M4n there is no error, just no tree shaking. It loads the whole library not forEach and merge methods.

Comment: @alexKhymenko that's odd. I build with prod and aot with no issues. Can you try adding types ? npm i --save @types/lodash ? I don't use them but it might solve your issue

Comment: @Pian0_M4n Again, it is not about issues with compilation. It is about tree shaking not working when importing like this. Do you understand what the effect of tree shaking is supposed to be?

Comment: @fnt that problem is long gone since typescript and ng updates

Comment: @Pian0_M4n What problem? The discussion here is not about the OP's issue, it is about tree shaking.

Comment: Yes @fnt. Shaking. It used to fail a while ago for lodash types not it works

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else runs into this issue and none of the above solutions work due to "Duplicate identifier" issues, run this:

```
npm install typings --global
```

With older versions of typings things mess up and you'll get a bunch of "Duplicate identifier" issues. Also you don't need to use `--ambient` anymore as far as I could tell.

So once typings is up to date, this should work (using the Angular 2 quickstart).

Run:

```
npm install lodash --save 
typings install lodash --save
```

First, add this to systemjs.config.js:

```
'lodash':                     'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
```

Now you can use this in any file: `import * as _ from 'lodash';`

Delete your typings folder and run `npm install` if you're still having issues.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that `npm install --save` will foster whatever dependency your app requires in production code.
As for "typings", it is only required by TypeScript, which is eventually transpiled in JavaScript. Therefore, you probably do not want to have them in production code. I suggest to put it in your project's `devDependencies` instead, by using

```
npm install --save-dev @types/lodash
```

or

```
npm install -D @types/lodash
```

(see Akash post for example). By the way, it's the way it is done in ng2 tuto.

Alternatively, here is how your package.json could look like:

```
{
    "name": "my-project-name",
    "version": "my-project-version",
    "scripts": {whatever scripts you need: start, lite, ...},
    // here comes the interesting part
    "dependencies": {
       "lodash": "^4.17.2"
    }
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.40"
    }
}
```

**just a tip**

The nice thing about `npm` is that you can start by simply do an `npm install --save` or `--save-dev` if you are not sure about the latest available version of the dependency you are looking for, and it will automatically set it for you in your `package.json` for further use.

Answer (score 4):

Partial import from **lodash** should work in **angular 4.1.x** using following notation:

```
let assign = require('lodash/assign');
```

Or use 'lodash-es' and import in module:

```
import { assign } from 'lodash-es';
```

Comment: ```import { assign } from 'lodash-es';``` seems to still import the whole library (judging by bundle size)

Answer (score 3):

I had created typings for `lodash-es` also, so now you can actually do the following

#### install

```
npm install lodash-es -S
npm install @types/lodash-es -D
```

#### usage

```
import kebabCase from "lodash-es/kebabCase";
const wings = kebabCase("chickenWings");
```

if you use rollup, i suggest using this instead of the `lodash` as it will be treeshaken properly.

Answer (score 2):

Install via `npm`.

```
$ npm install lodash --save
```

Now, `import` in the file:

```
$ import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

**ENV:**

> Angular CLI: 1.6.6
>   Node: 6.11.2
>   OS: darwin x64
>   Angular: 5.2.2
>   typescript: 2.4.2
>   webpack: 3.10.0

Answer (score 1):

1. Install lodash

`sudo npm install typings --global
npm install lodash --save 
typings install lodash --ambient --save`

2. In index.html, add map for lodash:

`System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      lodash: 'node_modules/lodash/index.js'
    }
  });`

3. In .ts code import lodash module

`import _ from 'lodash';`

Comment: It is throwing error: 
```$ typings install lodash --ambient --save
typings ERR! message https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/lodash/versions/latest responded with 407, expected it to equal 200```

Answer (score 1):

I am using ng2 with webpack, not system JS. Steps need for me were:

```
npm install underscore --save
typings install dt~underscore --global --save
```

and then in the file I wish to import underscore into:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

Answer (score 1):

Managing types via `typings` and `tsd` commands is ultimately deprecated in favor of using npm via `npm install @types/lodash`.

However, I struggled with "Cannot find module lodash" in import statement for a long time:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

Ultimately I realized Typescript will only load types from node_modules/@types start version 2, and my VsCode Language service was still using 1.8, so the editor was reporting errors.

If you're using VSCode you'll want to include

```
"typescript.tsdk":  "node_modules/typescript/lib"
```

in your VSCode settings.json file (for workspace settings) and make sure you have typescript version >= 2.0.0 installed via `npm install typescript@2.0.2 --save-dev`

After that my editor wouldn't complain about the import statement.

Answer (score 1):

if dosen't work after

```
$ npm install lodash --save 
$ npm install --save-dev @types/lodash
```

you try this and import lodash

```
typings install lodash --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Install all thru terminal:

```
npm install lodash --save
tsd install lodash --save
```

Add paths in index.html

```
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
        paths: {
            lodash: './node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
        }
    });
    System.import('app/init').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Import lodash at the top of the .ts file

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'
```

Comment: tsd is deprecated now. You should use typings

Comment: typings is deprecated now. You should use @types

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Angular 4.0.0 using the [preboot/angular-webpack](https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack), and had to go a slightly different route.

The solution provided by @Taytay mostly worked for me:

```
npm install --save lodash
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

and importing the functions into a given **.component.ts** file using:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

This works because there's no "default" exported class. The difference in mine was I needed to find the way that was provided to load in 3rd party libraries: **vendor.ts** which sat at:

```
src/vendor.ts
```

My **vendor.ts** file looks like this now:

```
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

import 'rxjs';
import 'lodash';

// Other vendors for example jQuery, Lodash or Bootstrap
// You can import js, ts, css, sass, ...
```

Comment: You should really dial down on importing the whole rxjs and everything from lodash...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too strange, but none of the above helped me, first of all, because I had properly installed the lodash (also re-installed via above suggestions).

So long story short the issue was connected with using `_.has` method from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#has).

I fixed it by simply using JS `in` operator.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --save @types/lodash`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash

Answer (score -1):

try >> `tsd install lodash --save`

Comment: tsd is deprecated now. You should use typings

Comment: typings is deprecated now. You should use @types.. :)

Comment: i am waiting for another deprecation comment ;)

Comment: deprecation is deprecated. err..don't blame me. u asked for that one ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can also go ahead and import via good old require, ie:

```
const _get: any = require('lodash.get');
```

This is the only thing that worked for us. Of course, make sure any require() calls come after imports.