# Angular 2 - Merging (extending) objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

How to merge 2 objects with Angular 2?

In AngularJS 1 we have the "merge" and "extend" functions:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

But apparently nothing in Angular 2!

Do you have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

Angular2 doesn't provide anything like this.

You can use for example [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
Object.assign(target, source_1, ..., source_n)
```

Comment: Be careful with IE. According to MDN it is not supported.

Comment: The Android browser doesn't support this either: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.assign

Comment: If you are using the Angular-CLI, find `poyfills.ts` and uncomment the code that supports IE9-11.

Answer (score 36):

The way to do it in Angular is with javascript's [Object Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) syntax or [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const obj = {...object1, ...object2}; // or
const obj = Object.assign({}, object1, object2);
```

The above options are **not supported by IE** natively.
So let's see what happens in each scenario...

### 1. Angular CLI

#### Version 8 and higher

In Angular CLI version 8 and higher, you don't need to take any additional actions. Applications are built using differential loading. This basically means that Angular will load a different javascript bundle for older browsers, which includes all the necessary polyfills. [Read more about browser support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#browser-support).

#### Older versions

If you are using older versions of the Angular CLI with a Typescript version less than 2.1 (quite old), then open `/src/polyfills.ts` and uncomment the following line:

```
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
```

This will enable the Object polyfill which provides cross browser support for `Object.assign()`.

### 2. Typescript

If you did not use Angular CLI, but you are using Typescript version 2.1 or greater, then you don't have to take any additional actions. Otherwise...

### 3. Plain Javascript

If you don't use Angular CLI or Typescript, then you can just import a polyfill into your project. There are plenty out there and here are a few ones:

---

[Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is a good option. You can use any of the [Object.assign()](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-assign) and [Object Spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread) polyfill plugins.

---

Another options is [core-js npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) that Angular CLI uses for its polyfills.

---

A [simple polyfill](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20x%3A%201%2C%20y%3A%20%22string%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0Avar%20newObj%20%3D%20%7B...obj%2C%20z%3A%203%2C%20y%3A%204%7D%3B) from Typescript's conversion into javascript:

```
Object.assign = Object.assign || function(t) {
    for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
        s = arguments[i];
        for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
            t[p] = s[p];
    }
    return t;
};
```

---

And lastly, the [MDN polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).

Comment: Object spread implement upon build time should be the exact solution, because mostly Angular 2+ users are building application with Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore/lodash library.
https://lodash.com/docs#merge

Just include it in your angular2/4 stack.
This question explains how: [Importing lodash into angular2 + typescript application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660265/importing-lodash-into-angular2-typescript-application)