# TypeScript typings in npm @types org packages

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've noticed there's an npm organization [@types](https://www.npmjs.com/~types), which contains typing packages, but can't find any documentation on it. How are these meant to be used?

Is it meant to be used with [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) tool? If so, how to install them? For instance, there's a [`@types/openlayers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/openlayers) package, but `typings search npm:openlayers` returns nothing.

Is it meant to be used separately from the typings tool? E.g. installed directly with `npm`?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

As of TypeScript 2.0, *typings* is no longer required. The npm organization is an entity to setup a developers team. I believe Microsoft setup the @types organization in npm and added the TypeScript developer team to the organization. Packages on under the @types organization are published automatically from DefinitelyTyped using the types-publisher tool as per the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html).

In addition, to there is another way to add `types` to your packages:

**In your package.json**

If your package has a main `.js` file, you will need to indicate the main declaration file in your `package.json` file as well. Set the `types` property to point to your bundled declaration file. For example:

```
{
    "name": "awesome",
    "author": "Vandelay Industries",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "./lib/main.js",
    "types": "./lib/main.d.ts"
}
```

Note that the `"typings"` field is synonymous with `"types"`, and could be used as well.

Also note that if your main declaration file is named `index.d.ts` and lives at the root of the package (next to `index.js`) you do not need to mark the `"types"` property, though it is advisable to do so.

**Regarding searching types**

> For the most part, type declaration packages should always have the same name as the package name on npm, but prefixed with @types/, but if you need, you can check out https://aka.ms/types to find the package for your favorite library.

From - http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html

But when I did `npm search @types/openlayers`, I did not get any results. But doing the search from the web interface did return me the results. So I guess `npm search` does not search across organizations.

Comment: Great answer! Minor edits would be nice, but this does a much better job of explaining the current state.

Comment: Since you specify a single file in your ``package.json`` under the ``types`` property, I noticed you're talking about **bundled declaration file**. What would be the easiest way to achieve this in an automated build system like gulp?

Comment: Do I have to add the `"main"`field if the main is named index.js?

Comment: Many thanks for this *"Note that the `"typings"` field is synonymous with `"types"`, and could be used as well"*

Answer (score 45):

Announcement on the TypeScript blog answers this: [The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Summary:

The `@types` npm organization is for obtaining type definitions with `npm`. Using these type definitions is a feature is coming in TypeScript 2.0.

This will replace the current projects/tools such as [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) and [tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd), though these will continue to be supported for some time.

Comment: Hey Ron, So i'm trying to get these setup, but it doesn't seem like VSCode is realizing I have them installed. After using something like `core-js` w/ `npm i @types/core-js --save`, I can see it's in the folder, but the project still throws errors for things. Is there something else I should be doing? Do I need to let tsconfig be aware of @types or something? Like Sean said, there's no documentation anywhere for types yet :(

Comment: @MarkPieszak you have to be sure VSCode is using TS2.0. See how to install TypeScript locally and use it in VSCode here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Nightly-drops

Comment: Yup that was it @nino.porcino thank you :) `tsdk` needed to be pointed to a 2.0beta install of TS

Comment: at least for some team projects we're updating (and also in other GH projects we saw) one should also update `tsconfig.json` with a `"types"` array property listing those module names, e.g. `"types": ["core-js"]`

Answer (score 10):

This is going to be a feature that is rolled out in Typescript 2.0. This provides type support for UMD Modules/Libraries and their respective definitions.

See ([Built-in support for UMD module definitions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7125#issuecomment-210182488)) to get a better understanding of the issues currently with ambient typings.

Comment: Thank you! This is useful, but I don't see the GitHub issue discussing the @types npm org. Is the @types org specifically for UMD `/// <reference` scenario? Will the TypeScript compiler automatically look for types under `node_modules/@types` (as it looks for modules in `node_modules` when `'moduleResolution': 'node'`)? What does this mean for `typings` - it also handles ambient dependencies. Is it related in any way?