# Using scanner-js with Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I am currently attempting to use [Scanner-JS](http://asprise.com/document-scan-upload-image-browser/direct-to-server-php-asp.net-overview.html) in one of my Angular2 projects I have made to try to learn.

I am very new to Angular2, so this question may seem very simple to some of you.

I have installed scanner-js using npm

```
npm install scanner-js --save
```

Is there a way I can import this into my typescript?

I have attemped to do the following (please don't laugh)

```
import { scanner } from 'scanner-js'
```

But this didn't work I get an error saying

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: scanner is not defined
```

Would anybody be able to give me a push in the right direction on how to get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in an included `.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'scanner-js';
```

And then import your module as you specified. By default when you declare a module like that, it will have the `any` type.

Look at [working with other js libs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries) and [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) from the official handbook for more information.

With other popular libraries the `.d.ts` types file is already defined by other kind individuals and you can install it like:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/d3
```

Comment: Ok, so I have declared scanner-js in a file ending in .d.ts and then attempted to import the library in my component file using the following code "import * as scanner from 'scanner-js';" I have also tried "import {scanner} from 'scanner-js';" but both of these are giving the same error from my original question.

Comment: With regards to the @types is there a site with a list of available types?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548066/typescript-typings-in-npm-types-org-packages

Answer (score 1):

Replace line:

```
import { scanner } from 'scanner-js'
```

with:

```
declare let scanner;
```

and make sure you've added scanner.js script to index.html.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that it works with Angular 7+. Thanks for the help.