# what is @type folder in node_modules in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have node version 8.9.1
and npm version 5.5.1.

After installing packages using **npm install**, a folder named @types in node_modules is created. What is purpose of this folder?. Is it ok to delete it from node_modules folder?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548066/typescript-typings-in-npm-types-org-packages

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. But surely got some knowledge regarding @type. Thanks for efforts. :)

Comment: Added more relevant explanation

Comment: Run `npm ls @types/moduleName` to see where it comes from, one of your  dependency may require it.

Answer (score 1):

This @types scoped package is where we can find a ton of useful type definitions, such as for example the type definitions of node that allow us to use `require` for example.