# How do I use TS types from an NPM @types/<package-name> package?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using the [`ssh2-sftp-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client) NPM package and types for it are provided by [`@types/ssh2-sftp-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ssh2-sftp-client). I've both of them installed but no types are being picked up. This is what my `package.json` look like:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "description",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/ssh2": "^1.11.7",
    "@types/ssh2-sftp-client": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ssh2-sftp-client": "^9.0.4"
  }
}
```

There's this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39998720/10824322), however it seems to address types you declare yourself. Do I need to do further setup after installing any `@typings` package?

Edit... I forgot to add `tsconfig.json` file:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "cdk.out"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You might need to restart ts server to make it pick the types. Other than that it should work.

Comment: I'm using VSCode. How do I restart the server?

Comment: @António Conselheiro I've added the tsconfig to the question.

Comment: Hi @uzluisf I have come across the same problem. I am using ssh2-sftp-client and creating a Client instance fails. I have now added the same `@types` as you, but VSCode says: Module '"ssh2-sftp-client"' has no exported member 'Client'.ts(2305)

Wondering if you made any progress. Restarting VSCode doesn't solve anything in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Yury Tarabanko, I restarted the language server and that did the trick. On VSCode, press `Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + P` to bring up the command palette, and then search/run `Developer: Reload Window`.