# How to extend underscore using Typescript 2.0

Tags: typescript, underscore.js, mixins

I have the following snippet to extend underscore with sum function

```
//underscore.extension.ts    
import * as _ from "underscore"

declare module "underscore" {
    export interface UnderscoreStatic {
        sum(items: number[]): number;
    }
}

_.mixin({
    sum: items => { return _.reduce<number, number>(items, function (s, x) { return s + x; }, 0); }
});
```

However,using _.**sum**() gives me the "    Property 'sum' does not exist on type 'UnderscoreStatic'.

Well,anyone tell me the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: I know you asked for underscore, but lodash (which is a superset of underscore) can be extended like outlined in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660265/importing-lodash-into-angular2-typescript-application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking up this a bit more you also have global augmentation that can solve your problem (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)

```
import * as _ from "underscore"

declare global {
    interface UnderscoreStatic {
        sum(items: number[]): number;
    }
}

_.mixin({
    sum: items => { return _.reduce<number, number>(items, function (s, x) {     return s + x; }, 0); }
});
```

Since your mixin to underscore has to run at least one time, you have to include/require this modification early on, but you can use underscore package as normal after this has been mixed in.

Comment: I know this is plenty old, but I'm not actually able to get this to work. Even after that global augmentation declaration as described in this answer, it's still saying my new mixin is not part of UnderscoreStatic.

Comment: Typescript changes all the time so they may have changed this. You can try extending and import your new extension? Look at the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

typescript needs the definitions declared, and sum() isn't known. Have you tried to extend underscore as a class and declare sum as a static method?

then export your new extended underscore class to be used around your application?

EDIT;
Underscore does not have a constructor so you have to extend the interface and mixin your changes and return the new interface like this:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

interface UnderscoreExtended extends UnderscoreStatic {
    sum(items: number[]): number;
}

_.mixin({
    sum: items => { return _.reduce<number, number>(items, function (s, x) { return s + x; }, 0); }
});

export { UnderscoreExtended } // as UnderscoreStatic }

export default _ as UnderscoreExtended;
```

In your project you can import this extended underscore and use it as normally

```
import _ from '<your file containing extended underscore>';

_.isNumber(
    _.sum([1, 2])
);
```

Comment: i actually taken "Augmenting global/module scope from modules" declared in 1.8 for extending underscore.I think i have some misunderstanding  here.pseudo code are greatly appreciated.

Comment: that works but this is not exactly what i assumed.I wonder and want to make sure if its not possible to import just underscore itself rather than extended one to use the augmented methods of underscore

Comment: only way I think of then, is to modify the declaration files (d.ts) you have included in your project for underscore.