# using lodash with angular-cli@webpack?

Tags: angular, typescript

I recently upgraded my project to angular-cli@webpack in angular RC5.

I installed lodash using :

```
npm install lodash --save
```

then In my ts files, I am using it as:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Type, Input, OnChanges, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';    
declare var _:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'property-editor',
  templateUrl: 'property-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['property-editor.component.css']
})
export class PropertyEditorComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input('component-name') componentName: string;
  @Input('component-model') componentModel: RapidColumn;
  counter: number = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.isArray(this.componentModel));
  } 
//============================Data Type Operations==============================//
    isArray(data:any):boolean{                  
        return _.isArray(data);        
    }
    isObject(data:any){        
        return _.isObject(data);       
    }
    isString(data:any):boolean{        
        return _.isString(data);
    }     
}
```

But whenever I am trying to import it in my .ts files its giving errors.

any inputs?

Comment: I'd recommend you to go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36670005/2435473)

Comment: @PankajParkar But it it using systemJS, I am having webpack :(

Comment: @PankajParkar perhaps you only need:

import * as _ from 'lodash';


That worked for me and I am using angular-cli with webpack.

Comment: @BhushanGadekar webpack isn't module loader, webpack is **module bundler**

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks, I realised that webpack doesnt need any manual setup to refer to node_modules. got it working. :)

Comment: My point was webpack isn't a **module loader**, isn't it?

Comment: @BhushanGadekar how did you solve it? I have the same problem