# Importing visionmedia debug in Angular 2 app with System.js and how to log messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, debugging, systemjs

I am working on a MEAN stack app with Angular 2 frontend. I have successfully used `debug` in the express app. However I am unable to cleanly import debug in `app.components.ts` or `main.module.ts`. Any idea on how to proceed?

- `<script src="/node_modules/debug/debug.js"></script>` Results in error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`
- `<script>System.import('./node_modules/debug/debug.js');</script>` Not good either: `zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8002/ms.js 404 (Not Found)` Some dependency script not able to load.
- `import { debug } from '../../../node_modules/debug/debug.js';` inside any app file also gives error: `zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8002/ms.js 404 (Not Found); (index):25 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8002/ms.js(…)`

**Solved**

Finally solved it thanks to @candidJ. I highly recommend using this tool to debug your app. After finishing development, refactor all your `console.log()` statements into `debugApp()` instead of deleting them. Remember, you can namespace them per module, and enable/disable them individually or en-mass. These will prove very useful later on for other developers backtracking trough the code for maintenance or debugging.

Answer (score 2):

you need to have typings installed for `debug` library inorder to use it in `ts` file. typings manage your typescript defenitions.

> Typings is the simple way to manage and install TypeScript
>   definitions.

here how you can do it :

```
# Install Typings CLI utility.
  npm install typings --global    

# Find a definition by name.
typings search --name debug

# If you use the package as a module:
# Install non-global typings (defaults to "npm" source, configurable through `defaultSource` in `.typingsrc`).

typings install debug --save
```

then you can try importing it in your `index.html` (globally) using **either** way (as you have done):

- `<script src="/node_modules/debug/debug.js"></script>`
- `<script>System.import('./node_modules/debug/debug.js');</script>`

for more info on typings look : https://github.com/typings/typings

Comment: I have installed typings as recommended (globals and modules) and I'm still getting those errors. In `tsconfig.json` I have added `"compilerOptions": { "types": [ "core-js", "debug"], ...}.` When I run in cmd `npm run tsc -w` I get the following message: `error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'debug'.` I'm using typescript 2.0.3.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! It helped me figure out what to do next. I finally managed to print messages in console. Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39666118/1903781) for specific details.

Comment: just read your edited question. try using `this.debugApp = debug('app');
this.debugApp('test');` in constructor method of your component. I haven't worked with `debug.js` earlier.

Comment: @AdrianMoisa you eventually figured it out on your own. I learned a lot from this question :)

Comment: **Update:** [`typings` has been deprecated.](https://github.com/typings/typings) There are instructions on how to replace it, over in [its README](https://github.com/typings/typings)

Answer (score 2):

I took some inspiration from [Importing lodash into angular2 + typescript application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660265/importing-lodash-into-angular2-typescript-application) and finally figured out how to import it. No console errors and no compiler errors this time.

First I should mention: when upgrading from `typescript 1` to `typescript 2` the `typings` tool gets deprecated. Instead, `npm` package manager is used to install type definitions.

I followed these steps:

- `npm install debug --save`
- `npm install @types/debug --save`
- Mapped debug in `system.config.js`

**system.config.js:**

```
map: {
    'debug': '../node_modules/debug/browser.js',
    ...
}
```

- Import in any **.ts** file you need: `import * as debug from 'debug';`
- Optionally, if needed in **index.html** use: `<script>System.import('debug');</script>`

Untill now this should work, however a pesky error persists: `GET http://localhost:8002/ms.js 404 (Not Found)`. I fixed this by editing `node_modules/debug/debug.js`.

- Replace line 14: `exports.humanize = require('ms');` with `exports.humanize = require('node_modules/ms/index');`.

I am not sure what this implies for other use cases of `debug`. If you have any suggestions on how to improve this solution so it is not necessary to edit inside `node_modules/debug/debug.js` write a comment.

**Usage in browser**

Preferably in **app.component.ts** or **main.module.ts** write:

```
// Expose debugsApp in window object in order to access it from the console. 
// window.debug is already used by chrome. 
import * as debug from 'debug';
(<any>window).debugApp = debug; // The typescript way to extend window
```

In any other **.ts** file:

```
import * as Debug from 'debug';

var debug = Debug('app:someModule');
debug('Some message');
```

Finally in the **console** type as you need:

```
// Business as usual
debugApp.enable('*'); // Enable all
debugApp.enable('app'); // Enable app debugger
debugApp.enable('app:*'); // Enable app debuggers if they are namespaced
debugApp.enable('app:someModule'); // Enable someModule
debugApp.disable('*'); // Disable all
```

**EDIT**

I had an unexpected issue with this method. I could either load the server path or the frontend path for the debug script. So I had to do another improvisation.

**node_modules/debug/debug.js - Line 14**

```
if (typeof process === 'undefined') {
  exports.humanize = require('node_modules/ms/index.js');
} else {
  exports.humanize = require('ms');
}
```

This triggers another issue on itself. System.js likes to parse ahead the exports so this leads to abnormal behavior when `exports` statement is combined with an `if` statement. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39674574/1903781). Fortunately there is a fix. More details [here](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1454#issuecomment-249371539) thanks to @guybedford

In **system.config.js** add:

```
System.config({
    map: {
        ms: '@empty'
    }
});
```

In the end it's a patch-up job, but it works. Hopefully debug authors will suggest a better solution. Until then use this.