# Cannot find module "lodash," but it works

Tags: typescript, lodash

I'm trying to import lodash into a file in Angular2 with TypeScript built with Webpack. I always get an error `Cannot find module 'lodash'` or `Cannot find module 'lodash/submodule'`. However, the code still works properly and in fact if I don't do the `import` the code does not work properly.

```
import * as lodash from "lodash";
export class SomeService {
  fn(): any {
    return lodash.range(1, 2);
  }
}
```

This works properly, but I still get the `Cannot find module error`. I've also tried with `import lodash from "lodash"`, `import {range} from "lodash"` and `import * as range from "lodash/range"` among a few other things, but no matter what, I always get this error.

I've done `yarn add lodash` and `typings install lodash`. `node_modules/lodash` exists and has `node_ modules/lodash/range.js` exist. In fact, `import * as moment from "moment"` seems to be working fine.

Is there any way to get TypeScript to stop reporting this as an error?

Comment: Using TS 2.0? [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660265/importing-lodash-into-angular2-typescript-application). `@types/lodash` contains the types now.

Answer (score 2):

You should install the `@types/lodash` package via:

`npm install --save @types/lodash`