# angular2 returning lodash empty object

Tags: angular, lodash

angular2 is returning lodash as an empty object.

```
npm install lodash --save
npm install @types/lodash --save
```

Imported as below :

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

_ is empty - what i'm doing wrong?

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/1302

Comment: There's a similar question, did you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660265/importing-lodash-into-angular2-typescript-application

Comment: yes i tried those solution. I am not getting any error, but lodash is empty.

Comment: Should be the version, try a version below to see what happens!

Comment: "@types/lodash": "4.14.42", "lodash": "4.17.2"  no luck

Comment: But, the type version is different from the loadash version!!! makes no sense, there's something broken from the current version.

Comment: please let me know which version should i use, my friend is using the same process and everything is working fine on his system, even on his system angular-cli, node, typescript versions are same.

Answer (score 1):

With `"lodash": "^4.17.3"` on **dependencies** and `"@types/lodash": "^4.14.40"` on **devDependencies** of the *package.json* file I was able to do

> import * as lodash from 'lodash';

Wish that helps!