# "Cannot find module 'lodash'" when using import *

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am running the latest version of the angular2 cli 1.0.0-rc.4 and I am having a problem with one of my libraries.

When I try to import the lodash library (or any library) with

`import * as _ from 'lodash';`

I will get the following error when building:

```
ERROR in C:/tfsrepos/Nexus/Nexus/my-app/src/app/app.component.ts (2,20): Cannot find module 'lodash
.)
```

If I instead try to import using the line

```
import 'lodash';
```

then it builds fine.  However, now I can't use lodash because I haven't gotten it installed in any namespace.  The following line

```
_.fill(array, 'a');
```

produces the error

```
Cannot find name '_'.
```

What is the issue here?  My code works fine before I started trying to build using angular cli.

None of the solutions mentioned in this thread: [Importing lodash into angular2 + typescript application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660265/importing-lodash-into-angular2-typescript-application) work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing lodash into angular2 + typescript application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660265/importing-lodash-into-angular2-typescript-application)

Comment: I had seen that before but when ran npm install --save @types/lodas, I get more than a hundred errors building.  ERROR in C:/tfsrepos/Nexus/Nexus/my-app/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,21): ']' expect
ed.)
C:/tfsrepos/Nexus/Nexus/my-app/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,22): ';' expected.)
C:/tfsrepos/Nexus/Nexus/my-app/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,23): Declaration or stat
ement expected.)
C:/tfsrepos/Nexus/Nexus/my-app/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (11502,33): ']' expected.)
...

Comment: My co-worker has found the solution to this problem.  I am surprised that no one has mentioned it before on the web.  I guess lodash isn't very popular.  The problem is due to angular cli using a lower version of typescript than what the lodash typings package was built with.  The solution is to force an older version of the typings to be used.  In packages.json, under the devDependencies seciont, include @types/lodash": "ts2.0".  Delete and reinstall the lodash typings via npm.  This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try use _ directly before from.

`import _ from 'lodash';`

Comment: No change.  Still can't find 'lodash'

Answer (score 0):

Use :
npm i --save-dev @types/lodash

and you can import in your file :

```
      import * as _ from 'lodash';
```