# ngFor removing duplicates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

How can I remove the duplicates from this ngFor? I'd like to do that on the HTML, not on the component?

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let primer of dataService.data" [value]="primer.type" id="primer">{{primer.type}}</mat-option>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Angular2 \*ngFor iteration, how do I output only unique values from the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867448/in-angular2-ngfor-iteration-how-do-i-output-only-unique-values-from-the-array)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you want to implement the fitering logic in the component? I think it would be the cleanest way to go.
For an examle look here: [Angular Pipe to Hide Duplicates from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726820/angular-pipe-to-hide-duplicates-from-array)
The solutions is not quite perfect, but it sould give you an idea.

But if you must do it in template, you could create a pipe that filters and just apply it to the data you are iterating over.

Comment: Yes I could and actually it's how I have at the moment. However the data comes from another component and sometimes I got "undefined" as the data takes a while to populate. For that reason I'd like to know how to do that(if possible) in the ngFor, even if its not the cleanest way. Thanks

Comment: Using an observable you could get rid of the undefined and notify the component about the availiable data. Then you could use the pipe()-Method to filter the duplicates. Using the async pipe you can display the Observable in the template accoridingly.