# How to get total no of count of a field in a Json Array using TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

I have a Json array.

```
 "user": {
            "value": [
                {

                    "customerNo": "1234"

                },
                {
                    "customerNo": "abcd"

                },
                {

                    "customerNo": "1234"

                }

            ]
        }
```

Here I want to get the count of total number of customer. I am getting it like this:

```
json.user.value.length;
```

And the **output** is **3**. But the thing is I have to avoid duplicate customer number.

As here **"1234"** is there 2 times. So my **output** should be **2**
How to do this using Typescript.

Comment: @Moriarty: I am not sure the `angular` tag was irrelevant - there was a comment above which used a `forEach` device in Angular (now deleted, for reasons I don't know).

Comment: @halfer Haven't seen it, but no problem if it has to be re-added again when the question changes.

Answer (score 2):

Use [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
var uniqueCustomer = _.uniqBy(json.user.value, 'customerNo');
var length = uniqueCustomer.length
```

Here is link which shows [How to use lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39209948/1791913) in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` to count the unique customers.

```js
const data = { 
  "user": {
      "value": [
          {

              "customerNo": "1234"

          },
          {
              "customerNo": "abcd"

          },
          {

              "customerNo": "1234"

          }

      ]
  }
};

function getCustomerCount(arr) {
  let tmp = [];
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(!tmp.includes(curr.customerNo)) {
      return tmp.push(curr.customerNo);
    }
    return acc;
  }, 0);
}

let customers = data.user.value;
let customerCount = getCustomerCount(customers);

console.log(customerCount);
```