# How to sort data coming from the API by date in Angular 4

Tags: arrays, json, angular, sorting, date

This is the JSON data i am fetching from POSTMAN. I want it to be ordered in a nearest to todays date. I tried many angular pipes but unfortunately nothings working. Any help would be great. I want to sort the date by the "broadcastOn" field. Thanks in advance.

```
[ {
        "messageId": "09ca0609-bde7-4360-9d3f-04d6878f874c",
        "broadcastOn": "2018-02-08T11:06:05.000Z",
        "message": "{"title":"Server Side Test 2","text":"Different Message again","image":"https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png","url":"https://www.google.co.in"}"
    },
    {
        "messageId": "0a5b4d0c-051e-4955-bd33-4d40c65ce8f7",
        "broadcastOn": "2018-02-08T10:36:27.000Z",
        "message": "{"title":"Broadcast","text":"Broadcast","image":"https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png","url":"https://www.google.co.in"}"
    },
    {
        "messageId": "0a98a3f3-aa30-4e82-825a-c8c7efcef741",
        "broadcastOn": "2018-02-08T11:45:00.000Z",
        "message": "{"title":"Me sending the message","text":"Me sending the message","image":"https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png","url":"https://www.google.co.in"}"
    },
    {
        "messageId": "0cb4e30f-756a-4730-a533-594ddcd45335",
        "broadcastOn": "2018-02-08T11:01:57.000Z",
        "message": "{"title":"Server Side Test","text":"Different Message","image":"https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png","url":"https://www.google.co.in"}"
    }
]
```

Im adding a snippet from the service section as well for your reference..

```
addMessage(message) {
    let header: Headers = new Headers();
        header.append('Authorization', 'bearer' + this.authservice.getAccessToken());
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: header});
    this.sent.push(message);
        return this.http.post('https://sexhops8j5.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/notifications/broadcast', message, options)
        .map(response => 
            { 
                    return response.json();  
            });     
    }
    getMessage(){
        let header: Headers = new Headers();
        header.append('Authorization', 'bearer' + this.authservice.getAccessToken());
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: header});
        return this.http.get('https://sexhops8j5.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/notifications/sent', options)
        .map(response => {
            let message=[];
            for(let item of response.json()){
                let parsedMessages = JSON.parse(item.message);
                message.push({...parsedMessages, BroadcastOn: item.broadcastOn,MessageId: item.messageId});
            }
            console.log(message);
                            return message;


        });
    }
```

I'm adding a snippet of the .ts file as well

```
  sendMessage(form){
   this.messageService.addMessage({message:this.form.value.string, title:this.form.value.titleText, url:this.form.value.imageurl, image:this.form.value.image, broadcastOn:this.date})
   .subscribe(message => { this.getSentMessages();console.log(message);}
     );
    this.message = ''; 
    this.inputImage='';
    this.inputTitle='';
    this.inputString='';
    this.inputUrl='';
  }
  getSentMessages(){
    this.messageService.getMessage()
    .subscribe(message => {this.sentMessages = message});
  }
```

Comment: What does your sorting code look like currently?

Comment: It isn't sorted as of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary lodash, nor moment. broadcastOn is a string. The date is yyy-mm-ddTHH:mm, so, if a date is bigger that other, the string is bigger that other

```
getSentMessages(){
    this.messageService.getMessage()
    .subscribe(message => {
     this.sentMessages = message.sort((a,b)=>{
           return a.broadcastOn==b.broadcastOn?0
                 :a.broadcastOn>b.broadcastOn?1:-1
      }));
     });
  }
```

Comment: Appreciate your help can please tell me where i should add your code Since I'm new to Angular 4

Comment: in subscribe you have a local variable "message", that is your messages. So, after received, save in this.message the messages sorted

Comment: Is this what you are saying??                                       
      getSentMessages(){
    this.messageService.getMessage()
    .subscribe(message => {this.sentMessages = message.sort((a,b)=>{
      return a.broadcastOn==b.broadcastOn?0
            :a.broadcastOn>b.broadcastOn?1:-1
})});
  }

Comment: I got it thanks a ton. I misspelled a word and hence I was not getting.. Thanks a lot you just made my day..

Comment: what should I do so as to print them in descending order??

Comment: @abhijith, if you want to sort in reverse order, you change the "sort function" return a.broadcastOn==b.broadcastOn?0               :a.broadcastOn>b.broadcastOn?-1:1. The "sort function" must be return 0 if two elements are equals, and 1 or -1 depending if the first element have to be first or not

Answer (score 0):

With help of `lodash` and `moment` you can do it like this :

```
var sortedMessages = _.sortBy(messages, function(o) { return  
    moment(o.broadcastOn); 
}).reverse();

//OR (With ES6 way)

var sortedMessages = _.sortBy(messages,(o) => moment(o.broadcastOn) ).reverse();
```

**[WORKING DEMO (Angular 5)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lodash-momet)**

```js
var messages = [ {
        "messageId": "09ca0609-bde7-4360-9d3f-04d6878f874c",
        "broadcastOn": "2018-02-08T11:06:05.000Z",
        "message": {"title":"Server Side Test 2","text":"Different Message again","image":"https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png","url":"https://www.google.co.in"}
    },
    {
        "messageId": "0a5b4d0c-051e-4955-bd33-4d40c65ce8f7",
        "broadcastOn": "2018-02-08T10:36:27.000Z",
        "message": {"title":"Broadcast","text":"Broadcast","image":"https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png","url":"https://www.google.co.in"}
    },
    {
        "messageId": "0a98a3f3-aa30-4e82-825a-c8c7efcef741",
        "broadcastOn": "2018-02-08T11:45:00.000Z",
        "message": {"title":"Me sending the message","text":"Me sending the message","image":"https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png","url":"https://www.google.co.in"}
    },
    {
        "messageId": "0cb4e30f-756a-4730-a533-594ddcd45335",
        "broadcastOn": "2018-02-08T11:01:57.000Z",
        "message": {"title":"Server Side Test","text":"Different Message","image":"https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png","url":"https://www.google.co.in"}
    }
]

var sortedMessages = _.sortBy(messages, function(o) { return  moment(o.broadcastOn); })
.reverse();

console.log(sortedMessages);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks brother.  The array of JSON data is coming from the backend. Since I'm new to angular I don't know where to add the code snippet which you sent should i include it in the .ts file or in the .service file. Thanks in advance

Comment: The scripts which you sent where should I include it. I'm working in Angular 4

Comment: @abhijith , then you gonna learn something new today , read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660265/importing-lodash-into-angular2-typescript-application

Comment: Thanks @Vivek i went through the process which you sent can you please tell me how can i use it without reverse function.

Comment: remove `reverse` it's just JavaScript function

Comment: This is my .ts file@Vivek                          sendMessage(form){
   this.messageService.addMessage({message:this.form.value.string, title:this.form.value.titleText, url:this.form.value.imageurl, image:this.form.value.image, broadcastOn:this.date})
   .subscribe(message => { this.getSentMessages();console.log(message);}
     );
    this.message = ''; 
    this.inputImage='';
    this.inputTitle='';
    this.inputString='';
    this.inputUrl='';
  }
  getSentMessages(){
    this.messageService.getMessage()
    .subscribe(message => {this.sentMessages = message});
  }

Comment: Hey @Vivek where should i add this code                                                  
      var sortedMessages = _.sortBy(messages,(o) => moment(o.broadcastOn) ).reverse();

Comment: within `getSentMessages` function instead of `this.sentMessages = message` put  `this.sentMessages = _.sortBy(message,(o) => moment(o.broadcastOn) ).reverse();`

Comment: you have to follow the same steps as you have follow for the lodash to install momnet

Comment: i added moment but the output which I'm seeing doesn't seem to be sorted... Anyways thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @abhijith , code is 100% correct , as you can check that by running the snippet , all you need is to implement in Angular way

Comment: @abhijith , please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lodash-momet

Comment: getSentMessages(){
    this.messageService.getMessage()
    .subscribe(message => {this.sentMessages = _.sortBy(message,(o) => moment(o.broadcastOn) ).reverse();});
  }  Iadded like this

Comment: neither i am getting an error nor my problem is getting solved... Anyways thanks @Vivek.

Comment: @abhijith , Create a demo just like me , then I can help furthure , Please also upvote/accept the answer as you like

Comment: Thanks a ton @Vivek.. I had misspelled a word and hence was not getting the output.. I have upvoted.. Thank you once again

Comment: @abhijith , Glad to know , please accept the answer :D