# IntelliJ Why don't all methods show up on Insight? Lodash

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, lodash, intellisense, intellij-14

Fairly new to Angular and Lodash and wasted a bunch of time yesterday trying to get some Lodash stuff to work. Got all caught up in the fact that the tag insight was not finding things and thought that it was not present in the library but it was.

For example in the image below you can see that the IDE detects what the _.findIndex is but _.difference it unknown.

It does it on both systems that I am working on.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to correct the behavior?

[image]

Comment: Do you have lodash typings installed?

Comment: @Oksana Thank you. I had to Google lodash typings and found a post here in SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660265/importing-lodash-into-angular2-typescript-application. This led me to npm install of the @types/lodash which at least show me completion and and Ctrl click will work. It does not highlight as in findIndex but it is much better now. Post as an answer and I'll mark it as such. Thanks again.