# Smart Compare json files

Tags: json, compare

Say I have 2 json files.

#1

```json
{
"ID": 1,
"Value": "A"
}
{
"ID": 2,
"Value": "B",
}
```

#2

```json
{
"ID": 2,
"Value": "B"
},
{
"ID": 1,
"Value": "A",
}
```

I would like a compare that says these 2 files are the same.
Just because they are not in the same order, they are not different.
Are there any tools that will tell me they are the same?

thanks

I have tried online tools such as
https://www.jsondiff.com/

But they just do a not smart compare.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two JSON have the same properties without order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049303/how-to-compare-two-json-have-the-same-properties-without-order)

Comment: Neither set of data is valid JSON.  It's not properly nested (wrapped in `[]` perhaps), missing a comma between them (if it is meant to be a list) and the extra commas  on some of the values are wrong.  If it is a list, lists are ordered, so they are **not** the same.  Your online tool should have told you that.