# Object comparison based on keys

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to compare the object by only KEYS.

```
var obj1 = [ {"depid": "100", "depname": ""}, {"city": "abc", "state": "xyz"}, {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "contactno": {"ph": 12345, "mob": 485428428}} ];
var obj2 = [ {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "contactno": {"ph": 12345, "mob": 485428428}}, {"depid": "100", "depname": "role"}, {"city": "abc", "state": "xyz"} ];
```

> For example, If we compare object in obj1 {"depid": "100", "depname":
>   ""} with obj2 {"depid": "100", "depname": "role"}, must return true.
>   Since the keys are same. I need to set the values of obj2 in obj1.

```
//Expected result
obj1 = [ {"depid": "100", "depname": "role"}, {"city": "abc", "state": "xyz"}, {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "contactno": {"ph": 12345, "mob": 485428428}} ]
```

[I have tried the solution provided in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099886/comparing-two-array-of-objects/29100767?noredirect=1#comment46439483_29100767) But still not able to compare only on object keys and update the values from obj2 to obj1

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: This is not JSON, it's just a POJO (plain old JavaScript object).

Comment: Provided link is not valid

Answer (score 0):

This function checks: for each object in obj1, it will look for each key in obj2. So it is checking if deptid is present in obj2, if it is then return true. If

```
var f = function(obj1, obj2){
    console.log('Starting...', obj1.length);
    for(var i in obj1){
        var memberObj1 = obj1[i];
        var memberObj1Keys = Object.keys(memberObj1);
        console.log('Keys in each object', memberObj1Keys);
        // console.log('Checking for ', memberObj1);
        for(var j in obj2){
            var memberObj2 = obj2[j];
            console.log('Object2 ', memberObj2);
            for(var eachKey in memberObj1Keys){
                console.log('Looking for %s in obj2', memberObj1Keys[eachKey]);
                if(memberObj2[memberObj1Keys[eachKey]]){
                    console.log('Found');
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log('======================');
    }
 return false;
}
```

using the function.

```
var result = f(obj1, obj2);
console.log(result);
```

This is quick implementation for your problem. I have not tried to optimize the loop till now.

Any edit is welcome.