# How can we compare array of JSON objects?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have two objects

```
 "Conditions1": [
    {
       "fieldToken": "value1",
       "uniqueName": "value2",
       "conditionOperator": ">",
       "conditionValue": "value3"
     },
     {
       "fieldToken": "value1",
       "uniqueName": "value2",
       "conditionOperator": "==",
       "conditionValue": "value3"
     }
  ]

 "Conditions2": [
     {
       "fieldToken": "value1",
       "uniqueName": "value2",
       "conditionOperator": ">",
       "conditionValue": "value3"
      },
      {
        "fieldToken": "value1",
        "uniqueName": "value2",
        "conditionOperator": "==",
        "conditionValue": "value3"
      }
  ]
```

I want to compare these two objects whether they are equal or not. Both the objects are same but When I am  using equals method it is returning false. How can i compare array of json objects?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Not sure which language you are using but you can always stringify (with fields sorted) and compare the strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two json arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286671/comparing-two-json-arrays)

Comment: Its JAVA Language.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"json object"*. [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an array or an object). When it is decoded, the original data structure is restored (but it is not JSON or related to JSON in any way).

Comment: Json library? You can check its documentation

Comment: Convert to objects and compare

Comment: why don't you create a java schema, then use a java comparator on it?

Comment: Do you have this json in file or String?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As you have two objects.
take it in two variable and then make it string for both.

e.g.

```
    var a = Conditions1.toString();
    var b = Conditions2.toString();

    if(Conditions1.toString() === Conditions2.toString()){
        console.log("matched")
     }
```

***Note: above two matched only when both object are same.***

Comment: it won't work if the order of json objects within the arrays are different

Comment: in that case, it will return false, because if the arrays are different then it will not matched and return false.

Comment: its all depends on the definition of "equals" : i.e. should we consider the order (e.g. List) or not (e.g Set)?

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing as a JSONObject if you use package org.json.  You create a JSONObject:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

    JSONObject firstJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject secondJson = new JSONObject();
    firstJson.put("test1", "value1");
    secondJson.put("test1", "value1");  // change value1 to something else to test
    boolean result = firstJson.similar(secondJson);
    System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

Change value1 or any of the values to test.  It will print true or false depending on your test values.  The source code says: "They must contain the same set of names which must be associated with similar values." The source can be found here: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java

To test an array of JSONObjects, use JSONArray from the same package, and break the array up into individual JSONObjects to compare them.